# Group functions within class

Tags: php, class, oop

I have a class where I have similar functions that are related to different endpoints

```
class MyClass {

    public function case1_changeOrder() {

    }

    public function case1_changeLimit() {

    }

    public function case2_changeOrder() {

    }

    public function case2_changeLimit() {

    }


}
```

Is it possible to group those functions somehow so I can get rid of the prefix and do something like

```
$mc = new MyClass();
$mc->case1->changeOrder();
$mc->case2->changeOrder();
```

instead of

```
$mc = new MyClass();
$mc->case1_changeOrder();
$mc->case2_changeOrder();
```

Comment: Can you explain the actual goal of this class? There are many solutions (some given below) but it's impossible to say which is best unless we know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Rather than thinking "how do I group functions within this class", you need to think more broadly about what functions and classes you need. You mention "different endpoints", so think about how these endpoints are represented in your application. And ask yourself what the class you currently have represents - has it just evolved as a place to store some methods because you weren't sure where they belonged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with Composition, but it seems to me that it won't be good design because it is better to use composition the way it is meant to be (A has a B) not just for grouping.

If the operations are similar do it with an abstract base class and inheritance like so (you will have the added benefit of using polimorphism later if you need to):

```
abstract class GenericCase
{   
    abstract public function changeLimit();
    abstract public function changeOrder();
}
```

Then two classes that inherit from the base class:

```
class Case1 extends GenericCase
{
    public function changeLimit()
    {
        //... case 1 implementation
    }

    public function changeOrder()
    {
        //... case 2 implementation
    }
}

class Case2 extends GenericCase
{
    public function changeLimit()
    {
        //... case 2 implementation
    }

    public function changeOrder()
    {
        //... case 2 implementation 
    }
}
```

Or you can achieve the same using a common interface. It really is a matter of preference in this case. See [this tutorial for more details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-and-applying-polymorphism-in-php--net-14362).

If you insist of doing it with composition to have the exact structure you asked for, see section *Composition - Association and Aggregation* [here](http://nefariousdesigns.co.uk/object-oriented-php-part-2-relationships.html)

Good luck.